# Youtube API videoEmbeddable filter not working?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube search API with the following parameters:

```
google.youtube('v3').search.list({
  part: 'id,snippet',
  videoCategoryId: '10',
  key: process.env.YOUTUBE_KEY,
  maxResults: 5,
  q: query,
  type: 'video',
  regionCode: 'FR',
  order: 'relevance',
  videoEmbeddable: true,
}, callback);
```

But when I try to embed it on my website, I get:

[image: Youtube impossible embed]

Which literally translates with:

> Part of this video comes from Recision, which blocked its diffusion on this website or app, watch it on youtube

(Sorry I could not get the error message in English, if someone has, please edit so that the question becomes easier to find...)

Ain't the `videoEmbeddable` and the `regionCode` supposed to filter those videos out of my search?

If not, how can I filter those?

Cheers